# Validation with @Valid and BindingResult in Spring MVC isn't working

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, spring-mvc, post

I have a form with which you can register an event/save it to the database and I don't want the fields to be empty. If they're empty, a message should be shown and the event shouldn't be saved to the database.

To handle this, there is this method on EventController class:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/registerEvent")
public String form(@Valid Event event,
                   BindingResult bindingResult, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
                "Couldn't register this event. Check all fields and try again.");
        return "redirect:/registerEvent";
    }

    eventRepository.save(event);
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
            "Event successfully registered!");

    return "redirect:/registerEvent";
}
```

And this is how the Event class looks like:

```
//imports

@Entity
public class Event implements Serializable {

    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    @NotEmpty
    private String venue;

    @NotNull
    private LocalDate date;

    @NotNull
    private LocalTime time;


//other attributes and any methods
```

For what it's worth, this is registerEvent html page:

```
<div class="row container">
    <p>Name: <span th:text="${event.name}"></span></p>
    <p>Venue: <span th:text="${event.venue}"></span></p>
    <p>Date: <span th:text="${event.date}"></span></p>
    <p>Time: <span th:text="${event.time}"></span></p>

    <h5 style="text-align: center;">You can sign up for "<span th:text="${event.name}"></span>" by filling the form below:</h5>
    <form method="post">
        Name: <input type="text" value="" name="name" id="name">
        Rg: <input type="text" value="" name="rg" id="rg">
        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Sign up
            <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
        </button>
    </form>

    <th:block th:include="validationMessage"></th:block>

<!--etc.-->
```

Which calls validationMessage.html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Validation message</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert" th:if="${not #strings.isEmpty(message)}">
    <h5 th:text="${message}" style="color: blue;"></h5>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, if I leave the fields empty and submit them this way, it looks like the "empty" event doesn't trigger bindingResult.hasNoErrors() and still gets saved to the database anyway — with NULL date and time and empty name and venue.

I'd expect the message "couldn't register the event..." in this case, but I always get "event successfully registered" no matter what.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing [`redirectAttributes.addAttribute(attributeName, attributeValue);`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html#addAttribute(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object)), can you try by adding them ?

`redirectAttributes.addAttribute("name", event.getName());`, etc...

You can find more info [here](https://zetcode.com/spring/bindingresult/).

Also, in most cases, you shouldn't use an entity as a `DTO`. I recommend that you first create a service which you call and in which you map your `DTO` to an entity, then you call your `eventRepository` to save that entity. More info on `DTO pattern` [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-dto-pattern), and on controller-service-repository architecture [here](https://tom-collings.medium.com/controller-service-repository-16e29a4684e5)